# Show the input data PHP

Tags: php, post, input

I'm used to using CIN, of C++, to get a input into a var... Its really EASY! 
So, I'm starting learn PHP.
And, I'm testing show on the screen what the user input in a form.
I know its a easy thing, but I am not achieving.

The form is in this file:
- html5.html

```
<div id="form">
<form action="test.php" method="post" >
<label for="code"> Code </label> <br />
<input type="password" id="coded" name="code" /> <br /> <br />
<hr />
<select name="modo-log[]" id="choose">
<option class="select_mod" value="professor">Professor</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="student" selected="selected">Student</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="user">User</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="adm">Adm</option>
</select>
<hr />
<button> Entrar </button> 
</form>
```

And the PHP file:
- test.php

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];
echo "$code";

$type_entered = $_POST['modo-log'];
echo "$type_enterd";
?>
```

But, I dont Know what I'm doing wrong...
The page just gets blank.

Help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` in the file to see *exactly* what is coming back from the client.

Comment: I don't see any submit button.. also you are trying to `echo` an array, you don't need this `modo-log[]`

Comment: have you opened your php url directly via browser? What do you see? it is something like http://localhost/your-app/test.php

Comment: The var_dump doesnt returns any result, too. I cannot understand this. Not even the type of data I can see on the screen...

Comment: I opened the html5.html, in the /var/www. So, when I click on the button, I see: html5.html/test.php.

Comment: So in www directory `html5.html` and `test.php` are there. right?

Comment: For sure.... I am not too idiot. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="submit"` attribute in `<button>` tag. SO that it will submit your form request

Change

```
  <button> Entrar </button>
```

to

```
  <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
```

Comment: Please do print_r($_POST) in test.php

Comment: Not even blank array?

Comment: Absolutely ANYTHING. At least looking at page source.

Answer (score 0):

This following setup should tell you whats wrong :)

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>

<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post" >
<label for="code"> Code </label> <br />
<input type="password" id="coded" name="code" /> <br /> <br />
<hr />
<select name="modo-log[]" id="choose">
<option class="select_mod" value="professor">Professor</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="student" selected="selected">Student</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="user">User</option>
<option class="select_mod" value="adm">Adm</option>
</select>
<hr />
<button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>


<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: Anything. The page keepts normal when I pressed 'submit'.

Comment: Sorry somehow half of the code didn't show up but i fixed it now please add the first php codes shown above. :)

Comment: The pages stay on the form.

Comment: Don't you get the values in a array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that my apache is wrong installed...
It'snt possible! I cannot do a simple test!

When I suspected the trouble was the apache, I tryed only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
$varr_1 = 1;
$varr_2 = 2;
$varr_3 = $varr_1 + $varr_2;
echo $varr_3;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And I didn't got any result. The page gets blank yet.

thanks to those who tried to help, I'll create a website on 000webhost to run php, whereas I've already tryed reinstalling the apache.
I'm sad....
Bye

Comment: WELL, TESTED AND CONFIRMED! The trouble was my internal server. Sorry for the ask. Thanks for replying!